# Coin payment from pocket of user

Tags: python-3.x, payment

I'm trying to write a program in Python3 that would prompt us to enter the amount of money to pay and then the number of coins we have (2 pounds, 1 pound, 50p, 2-p, 10p, 5p, 2p, 1p). It should give back in the list of integers how many coins of the specific value we used as well as change (float) if we didn't manage to pay the whole amount.
The first 8 numbers of the returned list represent coins that should be paid, using the same ordering as the input list, pocket.
The last number of the returned list gives the amount of money that the android should get back as change.
So, if we can pay the exact money, this will be 0; but if the money in the pocket is enough, but we do not have the right coins to pay the exact amount, this will be the amount of change that will be returned.
The total of the coins paid must be the exact amount if it is possible to pay that.
If it is not possible to pay the exact amount, the amount paid must be the lowest amount that covers the cost - the change returned should be as low as possible,
Ideally, we should pay using the most coins possible.

The code I tried to use is:

```
def pay_with_coins_from_pocket( amount, pocket ): #pocket - numbers of coins we have

    number_of_coins = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] #number of coins we will use and amount of change
    amount=amount*100 #in pennies
    amount_of_change=0
    values_of_coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
    number_of_coins_used=0
    money_in_pocket=0
    i=0 # "counter"
    money_in_pocket=pocket[0]*200+pocket[1]*100+pocket[2]*50+pocket[3]*20+pocket[4]*10+pocket[5]*5+pocket[6]*2+pocket[7]*1
    if money_in_pocket<amount:
         print("False")
    else:
       while i<8:
           while (pocket[i]>0 and amount>0): # if it stays, I can't pay 1.62 with 2 pound coin): #and amount>=pocket_at_first):
                if amount-values_of_coins[i]>0:
                    amount=amount-values_of_coins[i]
                else:
                    amount=values_of_coins[i]-amount
                pocket[i]=pocket[i]-1 #one coin from specific pocket was used
                number_of_coins_used=number_of_coins_used+1 #another coin of specific value was used
                number_of_coins[i]=number_of_coins_used #another coin of specific value was used
                amount_of_change=amount
                number_of_coins[8]=amount_of_change/100
       i=i+1

    return number_of_coins
```

Comment: When I try e.x. put 8p as an amount and give 1x5p, 4x2p, 3x1p, I got back [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 0.0], so as if more than I had before. If I delate if statement checking whether amount-values_of_coins[i]>0 or <0 I got mostly right amount of coins but chage can be negative - I pay e.x. 9p in coins but I'm left with 1p in place of change in list.

Comment: Update: when I put 'print("Using coin type:", i)' after amount=values_of_coins[i]-amount (in a new line, with intend aligning same as with else and if, and ran test with an amount to pay 13p, with 10 coins of every value I got back lines of Using coin type: and every number from 0 to 6 was showed 10 times, with 7 being showed once at the end. I have no idea what's going on anymore:(